# How to put element inside Bootstrap 4 data-content?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap pop over where inside it I display my email.

However, I want to make that text clickable with a mail:to link. Problem is, the text that displays is inside quotes. I tried escaping it with backquotes, but this breaks everything.

Here is what I have:

```
<p><a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-secondary popover-test" data-toggle="popover" title="Email me:"
                  data-content="'<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">'Send Mail to:</a> templenaylor@gmail.com">Contact Me</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data-html="true"`

```
<p><a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-secondary popover-test" data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" title="Email me:" data-content="<a href=&quot;mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello&quot; target=&quot;_top&quot;>Send Mail to:</a> templenaylor@gmail.com">Contact
        Me</a>
</p>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/gnyGL0nWCc